# Problem with return statement

Tags: java, methods, return

I have problem with return statment >.< I want to store all magazine names into

```
ArrayList<String> ListNameMagazine = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have a DB; in the DB there is a table `name_magazine` and the data in `name_magazine` is

> Magazine1
>
> Magazine2
>
> Magazine3
>
> Magazine4

This my main:

```
    ShowData Show = new ShowData();

    int HowManyMagazine = Show.HowManyMagazine(1); // to make sure there is how many Magazine name in my database

    //System.out.print(HowManyMagazine); //i want to make sure the data is out.

    String nmeMagazine = null; // this variable for get data from return statement 

    // i want to store in ListNameMagazine
    ArrayList<String> ListNameMagazine = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    for (int numbeer = 0;numbeer <= HowManyMagazine ; numbeer++)
    {
       //Store in 1 variable String, because if arrayList it's error
        nmeMagazine = Show.getResult("Select Name_Magazine from Magazine");
        // Store again in array list
        ListNameMagazine.add(nmeMagazine);
    }
    
    for (String s : ListNameMagazine)
    {
        System.out.println(s); // show the data
    }
```

This is my return statement:

```
public String getResult(String sql)
throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSetMetaData resultsetmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

    //String just_try = null;
    while (rs.next()) { 
         System.out.println("Result:"+rs.getString(1));
         //just_try = rs.getString(1);
         //return just_try;
    }
    return null;    //return just_try;
}
```

The problem is in return statement.

When the comment ( // ) I erase and the last return null; I delete. It become like here:

```
public String getResult(String sql)
throws SQLException
{         
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
     ResultSetMetaData resultsetmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
     String just_try = null;
     
     while (rs.next()) { 
         //System.out.println("Result:"+rs.getString(1));
        just_try = rs.getString(1);
        return just_try;
     }

     return just_try;
 }
```

When I show the data using this statement.

```
for (String s : ListNameMagazine)
    {
        System.out.println(s); // show the data
    }
```

the result only

> Magazine4
>
> Magazine4
>
> Magazine4
>
> Magazine4

@.@ I have confuse where the miss @.@

but when I show data in return statement like this

```
public String getResult(String sql)
throws SQLException
    {         
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSetMetaData resultsetmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
    String just_try = null;

    while (rs.next()) {     
        System.out.println("Result:"+rs.getString(1));
        //just_try = rs.getString(1);
        //return just_try;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The data show what I want. I know I only miss in somewhere but I don't know where that @.@. I hope you guys can found it .THX

Comment: Could someone with enough rep. or ferdinand yourself please correct the indentation on the code segments to make this a little more readable for anyone else please?

(it should be 4 spaces in front of any line you want to be code-formatted, and an additional 4 for any tab)

Comment: @xan - done.  It was painful, but it is done.

Comment: @ferdinand: quite apart from the code level problems, I worry about the database design.  You should read up on normalization.  It is far from clear that having columns Magazine1..Magazine4 is good database design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that **return** returns only one thing, and it will *return immediately and the function will exit*! You are retuning the name of a magazine **just_try**.

```
while (rs.next()) { 

    //System.out.println("Result:"+rs.getString(1));

   just_try = rs.getString(1);

  return just_try;

}
```

So, you start iterating through **rs**, and you get the name:

```
just_try = rs.getString(1);
```

And then you tell the code to return just_try.

```
return just_try;
```

At this point just_try will be returned and the function will exit! I think your problem is that you are expecting the function to keep going, and to keep returning values to the code that calls it, but this is not the way it works.

I suspect what you want to do is something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> ListNameMagazine;
ListNameMagazine = Show.getResult("Select Name_Magazine from Magazine");
```

then in the function getResult:

```
public ArrayList<String> getResult(String sql) throws SQLException {

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    ResultSetMetaData resultsetmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

    ArrayList<String> returnArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rs.next()) { 

        returnArrayList.add(rs.getString(1));

    }
    return returnArrayList;

}
```

Comment: No probs. Double check it because I made a mistake in the method name (the return type was still string, I forgot to change it).

Answer (score 3):

xan: Your method returns a String, while you try to return a list.

The signature must be changed to

```
public List<String> getResult(String sql) throws SQLException;
```

Comment: not List but ArrayList<String>

public ArrayList<String> getResult(String sql) throws SQLException 

^^ thx

Comment: No, it seriously should be List<String>.

Comment: thanks guys - I'm kinda busy at work and forgot to update the signature when I copied it from the questions.

Cheers!

Comment: You should return List<String>; the implementation doesn't really matter, and you might want to change it at a later date (if you decide there's a more appropriate list implementation to use). In this case, all you want to guarantee is that you can treat it like a list, so code to the interface.